# Graceful handling of the display of remote images that might no longer be there

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, user-interface

i am displaying remote images on my service

```
<img src="http://remote-site.com/imageX">
```

However, sometimes the image is already gone, so I would get 404s or just a plain text.

Question is -> how can i degrade to a generic image as soon as I get something that is not image type?

Actual code, whether in jQuery, Ruby, etc much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` event is fired when the image can't be loaded for any reason (connection error, HTTP 404, not image data, et cetera). A really simple inline example would be

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" onerror="this.src = 'generic-image.png';" />
```

Of course if you want to do this properly, do it in jQuery or another library:

```
$("img.external").bind("error", function() { // assuming your external images have this CSS class
    this.src = "generic-image.png";
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution! I am testing it out using 

  jQuery("img").bind("error", function() { 
     alert();
  });

But the event does not seem to trigger. What might i be doing wrong?

Comment: @ming yeow: The images might be loading before your event is attached. Perhaps using the inline method (or also setting the src attributes with JS) is better afterall.

Comment: that works! but it is really painful (and messy!) to write that everywhere it is needed. i wonder if there is a way to attach before load, something like live?

Answer (score 1):

If you write PHP you could use:

```
<?= (file_exists('http://remote-site.com/imageX'))?'<img src="http://remote-site.com/imageX">':'<img src="http://remote-site.com/genericImage.png">' ?>
```

This would check to see if the image is there, and display a generic image that you create and host somewhere if it does not.

I use this for User images in applications.  If they have not uploaded an image, the generic is displayed.

Are these images coming from a Database?

Comment: that is a great idea too. But would that be trying to retrieve the image twice -> one to check, one to load?

Comment: Good question, but no, it does not actually try to load or retrieve the image, but merely checks for its existence.  Similar to the Command Line 'dir' command which merely lists the files and folders but doesn't actually do anything with them.

The performance hit will be negligible, if that is your concern :)

Comment: hmmm, i am not storing the image in the db - it is remote

so wun it will hit the remote server twice? one to check , one to load

Comment: yes, it will indeed hit the remote server twice, but it won't actually try to load anything.  I assume these images are hosted by someone else.

Additionally, since PHP is rendered server side, if the file is not there, there is not even an ATTEMPT to load, as opposed to the jQuery method listed, which makes the load attempt and then goes about the business of reporting an error...which in turn must be caught and processed. Plus, this is a bit more succinct.  

In the end, Matti's response works and the difference is probably minimal :)